Problemas en crear un scroll correctamente en un ul
Estoy intentando crear un scroll dentro del ul para que me aparezcan datos. Sin embargo estoy encontrando problemas.
1.El primer problema es que he de poner el css del ul un max-height de 105 px para que me aparezca en todos los lados.
2.Si quito el max-heigt del max-accordion, la flecha no me aparece mas para expandirlo.
¿Que es lo que busco?
Que me aparezca el scroll en la parte derecha del max-accordion cuando tenga mas datos, que este sea solo uno y me permita desplazarme dentro del height.
Creo que el problema reside entre el max-height de ambos estilos css.
Muchas gracias
Muestro código:
HTML:
    <mat-expansion-panel class="card" [expanded]="false" [disabled]="noResults">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title class="title-card-header-valoracio">
                <img [src]="'assets/images/cronicitat/blue/qualitat-vida.svg'" style="width: 16px" />
                <span> Qualitat de vida </span>
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description class="" *ngIf="noResults">
                <div class="no-results-container-cronicitat">
                    <img class="no-results-image-valoracio" [src]="'assets/images/cronicitat/sense-dades.svg'" />
                </div>
                <div class="no-results-text-valoracio">No s'ha trobat resultats de la cerca.</div>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-container *ngIf="diagnostics.length > 0">
            <ul class="qualitat-card-body" *ngFor="let diagnostic of qualitatVidadGroup">
                <li class="valoracio-item">
                    <div class="diagnostic-name">
                        <span class="diagnostic-name-text">{{ diagnostic?.nom }} </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="diagnostic-interpretation">
                        <span class="diagnostic-interpretation-text">{{ diagnostic?.interpretacio }} </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="diagnostic-last-value">
                        <span *ngIf="diagnostic?.ultimValor" class="diagnostic-last-value-container diagnostic-last-value-text">{{ diagnostic?.ultimValor }} </span>
                        <span class="valoracio-date">{{ diagnostic?.data }} </span>
                        <mat-divider class="divider-valoracio" inset vertical></mat-divider>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

CSS:
.card-container-qualitat {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    width: 865px;
    max-height: 155px;
}
.qualitat-card-body {
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 420px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

